# spring oauth2 server returning html response

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

https://localhost:8443/Service/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials and i am passing client credentails in authorization header .
Case 1: when client credentials are correct Json response as it should be.
Case 2: when client credentials are in correct html response why ?
i am throwing throw new ClientRegistrationException(client) in loadclientbyId() if client not found in database.
any suggestion what might be wrong .thanks.

html response:[html response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/051eB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use your browser to test your endpoints.
Use a http client (i use Postman https://www.getpostman.com/ but there are others)

Comment: i found the root problem . client is authenticated by basic authentication filter .if authentication fails then there is no error handling.[link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java)